# How can I generate Semantic UI dynamic popup

Tags: html, jquery, popup, semantic-ui

First I create my dynamic table and add the `data-content` to the table. Then I add my popup code but it is not working. How can I solve this problem?

```js
var attachmentList = $("#newTable");
 var table = $('<table id="list-table"></table>')
.addClass('ui very basic table listpeople');
    var row = $("<tr class='tablerow'></tr>");
    $("<td>").addClass("collapsing general-popup")
      .attr("colspan", 3)
      .html("<center><div class='ui image fluid label clearfix ellipsisSection wait-popup' id='wait-approve' data-content='Hello Stackoverflow'>" + labelMessage + "</div></center>")
      .appendTo(row);
     table.append(row);
 attachmentList.append(table);
    $('.wait-popup').popup();
```

Comment: When do you use the variable `row` ? your example is not clear in that regard

Comment: i add row to dynamic table.